# Blinking Caps Lock with 16.04 LTS crash

Tags: system, crash

On what seems like random occasions, after putting my ASUS to sleep, I try to wake it but the Caps Lock is blinking.  I have to power my machine down to fix it.

Will post linux-crashdump when I have it.  In the meantime, if anyone knows a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Have you tried [TuxOnIce](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)?

Answer (score 0):

Ran linux-crashdump and then apport-retrace.  The result showed that Chromium was causing the problem.  Now when I put my machine to sleep, I make sure Chromium is closed and voila, no more crashes upon wake up.  Problem had to do with signature key and inability to get permissions.

Maybe I should go back to Firefox...